# iOS container view with custom segue - maintaining container size for children

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboardsegue, uicontainerview

I'm creating an application that will run through a 'session' with a user, it asks them questions and based on their responses will direct them to different screens within the storyboard. I based my solution loosely off of this blog post

http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

But rather than switching between two children, I am starting at the first and adding each new question screen to the child controller stack (I programmatically add buttons to go to the next question and previous question), as users will need the option to go back and change their answers while they're going through the session. Per the blog post, I use a custom segue that has an empty perform method

```
- (void)perform
{
    // Nothing. The ContainerViewController class handles all of the view
    // controller action.
}
```

And I implement my switching logic inside the parent

```
// Sets up the segue identifier and tells swapFromViewController: toViewController:
// function what view controllers to perform the segue one
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     // Instead of creating new VCs on each seque we want to hang on to existing
     // instances if we have it.
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierFirst]) {
         self.firstViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

         // If this is the very first time we're loading this we need to do
         // an initial load.
         [self addChildViewController:segue.destinationViewController];
         UIView* destView = ((UIViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).view;
         destView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
         destView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

         [self.view addSubview:destView];
         [segue.destinationViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
     }
     else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierSecond]) {
         self.secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         [self swapFromViewController:[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.currentChildVCIndex] toViewController:self.secondViewController];
     }
     else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierThird]) {
         self.thirdViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         [self swapFromViewController:[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.currentChildVCIndex] toViewController:self.thirdViewController];
     }
     else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierFourth]) {
         self.fourthViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         [self swapFromViewController:[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.currentChildVCIndex] toViewController:self.fourthViewController];
     }
     else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierFifth]) {
         self.fifthViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         [self swapFromViewController:[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.currentChildVCIndex] toViewController:self.fifthViewController];
     }
     else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierSixth]) {
         self.sixthViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         [self swapFromViewController:[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.currentChildVCIndex] toViewController:self.sixthViewController];
     }
}
```

The swap method

```
// Given two view controllers, transition from one to the other and add to the child controller stack so
// that we can maintain navigation
- (void)swapFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController toViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController
{
    toViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [fromViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:toViewController];

    [self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController toViewController:toViewController duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.currentChildController = toViewController;
        [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        self.transitionInProgress = NO;
    }];
}
```

When the next button is pressed

```
// When the next question button is pressed in the view containing this container,
// nextViewController is executed
- (void)nextViewController
{
    // If the view is still transitioning we must wait
    if (self.transitionInProgress) {
        return;
    }

    self.transitionInProgress = YES;

    // Set the next segue to occur based on what the current value is and what
    // the user has previously input
    self.currentSegueIdentifier = [self nextSegueForDirection:@"forward"];

    //increment curPage
    self.curPage++;
    [self.sessionBaseVC setProgressBarCurrentPage:self.curPage ofPages:self.numPages];


    // The following if-else block is for when we've navigated backwards and are coming
    // forward again. Rather than calling performSegueWithIdentifier, we already have
    // the next view controller on the stack, so just swap to it
    if (([self.currentSegueIdentifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierSecond]) && self.secondViewController) {
        [self swapFromViewController:self.currentChildController toViewController:self.secondViewController];
        return;
    }
    else if (([self.currentSegueIdentifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierThird]) && self.thirdViewController) {
        [self swapFromViewController:self.currentChildController toViewController:self.thirdViewController];
        return;
    }
    else if (([self.currentSegueIdentifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierFourth]) && self.fourthViewController) {
        [self swapFromViewController:self.currentChildController toViewController:self.fourthViewController];
        return;
    }
    else if (([self.currentSegueIdentifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierFifth]) && self.fifthViewController) {
        [self swapFromViewController:self.currentChildController toViewController:self.fifthViewController];
        return;
    }
    else if (([self.currentSegueIdentifier isEqualToString:SegueIdentifierSixth]) && self.sixthViewController) {
        [self swapFromViewController:self.currentChildController toViewController:self.sixthViewController];
        return;
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:self.currentSegueIdentifier sender:nil];
    self.currentChildVCIndex++;
}
```

The reason I am using a container view is that I need a progress bar as well as the previously mentioned next and previous question buttons to remain on the view, rather than changing to 'new' ones with each question.

Here's a link to a screenshot of my storyboard, with the purple and green representing transparent padding views (Purple will contain progress bar, and green the next and previous buttons).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwwkQ.png

So with all that information given, here's my problem:

I am using auto layout constraints to position the elements in each of the question screens, but the size of the container doesn't propagate down to these children (like it does with a push segue) when I use my custom empty segue. So this causing problems when I'm trying to size these views to fit for iPhone 3.5"-5.5" as well as all iPad sizes. 
Is it at all possible to have the children remain the same size as the container parent in interface builder so that I can properly apply constraints for each size class?

Comment: Sure. Just pin all four sides of the child controller's view to the container view with no padding. But why not embed a tab bar controller (with its tab bar bar hidden) in your container view, and use your button to set the selectedIndex of the tab bar controller to go the different children? That would use a lot less code, and you wouldn't have to deal with the sizing issue at all.

Comment: I actually had not thought of that, that will be so ridiculously easier! Haha, thank you!